# Flutter and DIO: HandshakeException: Connection terminated during handshake

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I'm using DIO for downloading images from network in my Flutter Application.
In general his is my code:

```
await Future.forEach(files, (file) async {
  print(1);
  entriesController.downloadIndex.value++;
  if (file["video"] != null && file["video"].isNotEmpty) {
    String videoPath = file["video"];

    var appDocDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String savePath = appDocDir.path + "/$uniqueID.mp4";
    await Dio().download(videoPath, savePath);
    await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(savePath);
  }
  if (file["video"] == null || file["video"].isEmpty) {
    print(2);
    String imagePath = file["image"];
    print(3);
    var appDocDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    print(4);
    String savePath = appDocDir.path + "/$uniqueID.jpg";
    print(5);
    try {
      await Dio().download(imagePath, savePath);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    print(6);
    await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(savePath);
  }
});
```

This is a loop which builds the network path to download the image and save them to the mobile gallery.

The problem: After maybe 50 downloaded images I get the following error on `await Dio().download(imagePath, savePath);` catch line:

**flutter: DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: HandshakeException: Connection terminated during handshake**

How can I solve this error? Is this maybe a timeout? By the way: The downloaded images are stored on DigitalOcean.